# if $0 \notin \overline{T(S_X)}$ then $T(X)$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let X banach space and $T:X \to X$ compact operator with rank not finite. I want to show that $0 \in \overline{T(S_{X})}$. my idea is to suppose that  $0 \notin  \overline{T(S_{X})}$ then if I can show that $T(X)$ is closed ended, because i can use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638640/compact-operator-with-closed-range-has-finite-dimensional-range).

My problem now is to show that if $0 \notin \overline{T(S_X)}$ then $T(X)$ is closed, Can someone help me show this?

Comment: What might $S_X$ be?

Comment: $S_X=\{x \in X : ||x||=1\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $0\notin\overline{T(S_X)}$, then there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $T(S_X)\cap B_\varepsilon(0)=\varnothing$.  Hence $\lVert T(x)\rVert\geq\varepsilon\lVert x\rVert$ for all $x\in X$, so $T$ is left-invertible.  But that means [$T(X)$ is closed and complemented](/questions/478999) in $X$.